# Client-Server functional tests

Tags: c++, unit-testing, design-patterns, functional-testing

I am writing a client and server library for local IPC. Client and Server both has classes which make use of named pipes to send data between two processes. I want to write functional test to test client-server libraries.

My idea is to create client in functionaltest, mock a server in a separate executable, launch server using CreateProcess and send data to server. But in such case I won't have any control on mock server and checking data sent by client cannot be validated on server.

Can anyone suggest me how to write client server functional test so I can validate functionality of both modules.

Here are couple of tests I'm thinking of,
1. Client connects to server.
2. Client disconnects gracefully from server.
3. Client sends some data to server.
4. Server disconnects client connection selectively.
5. Server shutdown/client shutdown
6. etc.

Thanks,
Ajay

Comment: Is the server specific to some application or is this a general client-server communication library?

Answer (score 0):

For testing, run the client and server code in the same process using separate threads.